# JPA: How can @Embedded entity have a type of itself as field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

My `Entity` looks like

```
@Entity
public class Market extends MutableEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Embedded
    private Version marketVersion; ..snipped
```

which has `@Embedded Version` as

```
@Embeddable
public class Version {
    private String number;
    private VersionType versionType;
    private DateTime publishedOn;
    private DateTime retiredOn;
    private Version parentVersion;
```

but this fails

```
08:12:23.481 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property number
08:12:23.481 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Market), mappingColumn=parentVersion, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}

    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.getExactOverriddenColumn(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:179)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

That cannot be done. Also it does not make too much sense to support such a construct, because then there is not any point where containment ends: `Version` contains `Version`, which contains `Version`, which contains `Version` etc.

In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> Direct or indirect circular containment dependencies among embeddable
>   classes are not permitted.

Comment: I see, thanks @Mikko, but what is the way then that I can have a `version` containing a `parentVersion` using `JPA`?

Comment: Typically in such a case Version is Entity and does have ManyToOne relationShip to itself (from child to parent). If bidirectional relationship is needed, then additionally OneToMany (collection valued) to other direction.